# Is it possible that the actual memory size of RTX 2080 Ti is smaller than RTX 1080 Ti

Tags: gpu

This is my first post, if there is something inappropriate, please bear with me. :)

Recently, I was running my program on two machines with different GPU type (one with *RTX 1080Ti* and another with *RTX 2080Ti*). For convenience, I will call the machine with **RTX 1080Ti as M1** and the other as **M2**.

Even I run totally the same program on two machine, but *M2* can't run as larger batch size as *M1* do.... (By the way, *M2* is indeed faster than *M1* under same parameter setting)

Then I check `nvdia-smi` and the information are shown below:

**Machine with RTX 1080Ti *(M1)***

`+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.00    Driver Version: 418.87.00    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 21%   19C    P8     8W / 250W |     10MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 21%   21C    P8     9W / 250W |     10MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+`

**Machine with RTX 2080Ti *(M2)***

`+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       Driver Version: 440.64       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:1D:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   32C    P2    48W / 250W |    914MiB / 11019MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:20:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   31C    P8     1W / 250W |     11MiB / 11019MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+`

As it shows, the memory in *M2* (11019 MiB) is a bit smaller than *M1* (11178 MiB). 
Since *M2* is a higher level product, shouldn’t it be better than the previous generation in all aspects of performance?

So...I would like to ask, could someone tell me why *M2* has lower memory capacity than *M1*?
And, is there any way I can try to increase the memory of *M2*? such as update the driver or...?

Comment: NVidia's website says they both have 11 GB of memory, and the slight variation may just be due to different amounts reserved for use by the hardware.  "Since M2 is a higher level product, shouldn’t it be better than the previous generation in all aspects of performance?"  Well... no.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge :)  So.. do you mean that I may not find the way to increase the memory because "the slight variation may just be due to different amounts reserved for use by the hardware"? Am I understanding this correctly?